# How to catch the error without exiting from the script?

Tags: perl

The below script exit when the peer port is not listening. I don't want it to exist instead it needs to keep trying. I know 'die' below will cause this, but is there a better way to capture the error without exiting.

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => $properties{peer_host},
    PeerPort => $properties{peer_port},
    Proto => 'tcp',
);
die "cannot connect to the server $!\n" unless $socket;
while(1){

 #send something to the port
}
```

Output:

```
cannot connect to the server Connection refused
```

Comment: FYI, IO::Socket::INET stores its construction failures in `$@`, _not_ in `$!`.  Surprising and [woefully under-documented as of 5.18.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html), but true.  (Something to do with ETIMEDOUT not existing on all supported systems, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to `die` might be helpful: http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html

and `warn`:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `warn`

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => $properties{peer_host},
    PeerPort => $properties{peer_port},
    Proto => 'tcp',
);
warn "cannot connect to the server $@\n" unless $socket;
while(1){

 #send something to the port
}
```